# Error when giving the command Grunt

Tags: json, gruntjs

I started to explore Grunt. Read several sites, I saw examples. Well, I created package.json and Gruntfile.js:

package.json http://pastebin.com/Kkt8fuXJ

Gruntfile.j http://pastebin.com/LnSmTzXZ

The organization of the folders of my project is:

```
root (index.html)
-src (where is package.json and Gruntfile.js)
-lib
 --css
  ---min
 --js
 --img
```

When I give the command grunt always happens this error:

```
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> Error: Unable to parse "package.json" file (Unexpected token }).
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

If i remove pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),:

```
        grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
        ^^^^^
Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR
>> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
Warning: Task "default" not found. Use --force to continue.

Aborted due to warnings.
```

What is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first error is caused by your package.json not being valid JSON. As far as I can see you're using an unnecessary comma at the end of line 9. Valid JSON would be this:

```
{
  "name": "EREBD",
  "description": "Site do evento EREBD XVII",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "Gruntfile.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "grunt": "~0.4.1",
    "grunt-contrib-cssmin": "~0.6.1",
    "grunt-contrib-imagemin": "~0.1.4"  //<- no comma there
  }
}
```

But you don't even need to import the package.json within the Gruntfile because you aren't using any properties of it anyways. So what's wrong with your Gruntfile? Well you are loading your npm tasks and defining your grunt tasks outside of the exported function. This is what it looks like the right way:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        // image optimization
        imagemin: {
            dist: {
                options: {
                    optimizationLevel: 4,
                    progressive: true
                },
                files: [{
                    expand: true,
                    cwd: '../lib/img/',
                                        src: '**/*',
                    dest: '../lib/img/'
                }]
            }
        },
        // minify css
        cssmin: {
                minify: {
                    expand: true,
                    src: ['../lib/css/*.css'],
                    dest: '../lib/css/min/',
                    ext: '.min.css'
                }
        }
    });

    // load tasks
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-imagemin');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-cssmin');

    // extra tasks

    // register task
    grunt.registerTask('default', [
        'imagemin',
        'cssmin'
    ]);
};
```

Comment: What a mistake by forgetting the comma. 
Thanks for your help. I change the package.json and Gruntfile.js BUT i still got an error:



`C:\Users\Felipe\Desktop\Test\src\Gruntfile.js:27

    );

    ^

Loading "Gruntfile.js" tasks...ERROR

>> SyntaxError: Unexpected token )

Warning: Task "cssmin" not found. Use --force to continue.


Aborted due to warnings.`

Comment: yes that solution it's not working for me , my Json file is well done